# SELECT AS casting columns implicitly

Tags: dbeaver

I have a table that contains `uuid varchar not null` and `id integer not null` columns.

If I execute this SQL statement
`select uuid, id, uuid as id from table;`
I get something like

```
uid                                 |id |id      |
------------------------------------|---|--------|
42e50e73-e673-4dd2-9ef2-d9aa94eece70| 11|      42|
03d92b01-0377-4ce9-8927-d092c6a03232| 12|       3|
96c9e980-2839-45ee-bc7c-456c2beaa589| 13|      96|
878979f5-6a21-465c-bcf3-55f6eb4ec412| 14|  878979|
491d1fbd-4652-42f7-b326-d3876656dc19| 15|     491|
cf00f2ac-d56a-4439-8a4a-8dd6193ca1b8| 16|        |
9cb13097-77ea-4656-8ccb-64420afdc994| 17|       9|
```

If I replace `as id` with anything but `id`, it works as expected.

As is clearly evident from this, Postgres is casting the `uuid` column into the same type as the `id` column. This works for all combinations of `column1 as column2` where `column1` is cast to `column2` type.

Why?

I am using Postgres 12.2 on MacOS. I tried the same on MySQL 5.7.28 and it doesn't perform the casting. I am aware this is not a practical query because of name conflicts, but the result is somewhat unexpected.

Comment: Duplicating names in output is bad practice itself and AFAIR non-standard extension.

Comment: ... so don't be surprised that such extension has some secondary effects unsafe for you.

Comment: @Akina Just to clarify, `select uuid, uuid as id from table;` would cast it too. I understand it is a bad practice, I just wanted to understand if there's some rationale behind this

Comment: Field in a structure is identified by its name. When server needs to get the info about field datatype it searches field definition block by its name, and it gets the former block which's name matches. So while searching the datatype for 2nd copy it finds the definition for 1st copy - and uses it. And I think it is release-dependent...

Comment: `select uuid, uuid as id from table` clearly should not cast. If it does - then it's a bug, since there is nothing wrong with the query. You might not know that an `id` column already exists in the table.  And I can't replicate the issue on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aad74d38d05658abcd3d39557c8892ec). What about `select uuid as id from table` - Does it cast too?

Comment: PS. I have tested 3 online fiddles - none shows described effect (more than 30 postgres and mysql/mariadb builds tested). All versions available on fiddles uses positional field parameters definition. Please specify full version string for a server which has described issue.

Comment: I don't think Postgres does this. Which SQL client are you using?

Comment: Huh. It was my DB manager `DBeaver` formatting the results. Disabling a configuration key `Read table metadata (unique keys)` fixed it. Closing.

Comment: @gargsms Add DBeaver tag to the question and write an answer, rather than closing the question. You might be not the only one with that issue.